# Delete managed object from context without save it

Tags: swift, core-data

I try to create new managed object in core data as shown in the code bellow and then when user cancel the implementation I want to delete the new managed object from the view context (without save it in core data), but when I try to be sure the object is deleted It's look its still in the context and not deleted.

```
    let context = PersistenceController.viewContext
    let list = ListOfTasks(context: context)
    context.delete(list)
    
    if list.isDeleted {
        print("Object has been marked for deletion")
    } else {
        print("Object has not been marked for deletion")
    }
    
    do {
        try context.save()
        print("✅ Delete managed object from context")
    } catch {
        print("❌ Error deleting managed object from context \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Comment: You can not delete an object from a context without calling save() on the context.

Comment: A better way is to add a temporary child context and create the object there. If the user cancels the operation the object is dropped silently, otherwise the object is passed to the parent context and is saved.

Comment: I use `backgroundContext`/`child` contexts, and call `reset()` on it when user cancel, affecting then only the entities on that context. But when "mixed", it need more logic.

Comment: If I use child context when creating a new managed object and then when the user cancels it I should call reset or rollback on child context or view context? I just don't want to create many objects then the user cancels, and all these objects will still be in memory.

Comment: The child context is temporary. When canceled It will be thrown away together with the unused records.